# node.js - get value of json request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, appjs

How do I get the value of json data sent from client with ajax in node.js?
I tried so many examples and q&a but still it's not working. 
I'm totally new to node.js so my question could be dumb.
I got my codes below. Please kindly point me out where and what are wrong. I'm totally lost.

What i need is the value "TEST" from data of the json.

I tried req.body.data

Client [html]

```
$.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/getFromDB',
      //data:JSON.stringify({"sql":"SELECT * FROM Track"}),
      data: '{"data": "TEST"}',
      success:function(data) {
        $('#disco').html(data);
      },
      error:function() {
        $('#disco').html('Error connecting to the server.');
      }
    });
```

node.js

```
var app   = module.exports = require('appjs');
var http  = require('http');
var url   = require('url');
var fs    = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  var value;

  if(path == "/getFromDB") {

    // req = JSON.parse(req);
    // var testshit1 = parser(req.data);

    req.on('data', function (data) {
      value = JSON.parse(data);
    });

    // ------- e.o test -------

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
    });
    res.end('value = ' + value);
  }

}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` in `req.on('data', function(data) { ... })` is a [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), you need to convert it to a string first.  Also, you could receive any number of `data` events that need to be put together to make up the request body. With those things in mind, the steps are:

1. Create a variable to hold your request body.
2. When you receive a `data` event on your `req` object, append the data you receive to the variable that holds your request body.
3. When you receive an `end` event on your `req` object, convert your request body to an object with `JSON.parse`.

Something like this:

```
var body = ""; // request body

req.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data.toString(); // convert data to string and append it to request body
});

req.on('end', function() {
    value = JSON.parse(body); // request is finished receiving data, parse it
});
```

Also, you'll most likely only want to respond with `res.writeHead`, `res.end`, etc once you've received the entire request body, so do that in the request's `end` event handler:

```
req.on('end', function() {
    value = JSON.parse(body); // request is finished receiving data, parse it

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
    });
    res.end('value = ' + value);
});
```

Comment: hi @Mike S , the code you gave works! however, the value is now changed to 'undefined' to '[Object Object]. can help lend me any advice for this? ^_^

Comment: Funny enough, you need to convert your JSON back in to a string when you call res.end().  Try: 'value = ' + JSON.stringify(value)

Comment: omg it took me so long to find that out, I used to use `querystring.parse(body)` and it never worked, don't know what's the difference though :\

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` in node is an object. use him.
Example:

```
req.on('data', function (data) {
      value = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log("SQL is " + value.sql);
    });
```

Comment: still "undefined". :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Local IP instead "localhost".

You can use getJSON() and then search into structure or if you know where is the value, access it directly:

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.1.1:8080/getFromDB', function (data) {
         var myVar = data.features[0].TEST;
         });
```